# How to combine multiple selectors within a class without prefixing every selector with & (parent operator) using SCSS?

Tags: sass

Let's say I have the following css:

```css
.foo {
    color: red;
}
.bar {
    color: blue;
}
```

I want the final css to look like this:

```css
.scope.foo {
  color: red;
}
.scope.bar {
  color: blue;
}
```

But I want to be able to just paste it somewhat unaltered, like some boilerplate that works like this:

```scss
.scope-class {
  ??? {
    // put css here
  }
}
```

Example:

```scss
.scope {
    & {
        .foo {
            color: red;
        }
        .bar {
            color: blue;
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously this doesn't work, but is there any way of archiving something like this, but keeping the css inside unaltered? I don't want to modify every selector like `&.foo` `&.bar`...

Comment: Take the { } away from the &. Put the .foo next to the &

Answer (score 0):

You could simply nest these classes in SCSS like this:

```scss
.scope {
    &.foo {
        color: red;
    }
    &.bar {
        color: blue;
    }
}
```

Comment: in the last sentence I said I didn't want to prefix every selector with &